# Where does Outlook 2007 save mail when I hit "Save"?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2007

I had like 2 pages written in Outlook. I hit Save and closed the window. Now I cannot find it, it is not in Drafts. Any ideas?

Comment: It is saved in the drafts folder. Nowhere else.

Comment: Then I'm ****. It is not there...

Comment: You sure you hit save? If you accidentally deleted then cleared your deleted files I may have a way to recover it.